# How to change the text of an element upon hover or being activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website that has a "Hire me" button centralized on the page.  It was created using the following code:

```
<div id="hire_me_button">
    <a href="contact.html"><h4 id="hire_me" class="button">Hire Me</h4></a>
</div>



#hire_me_button {
text-align: center;
width: 73.3%;
}

.button {
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 8em;
   height: 3em;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: .75rem .625rem;
   border-radius: 8px;
   color: white;
   font-size: .875rem;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-align: center;
}
```

What I would like to do is be a little playful by having the text change - either when someone hovers over the button or when it's been clicked on. I would like the text to change from "Hire me" to Wise choice" or "Wise Decision" depending on which would fit better.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F3j3p/1/ ?

Comment: I would suggest `CSS3`. **A quick google search yielded [THIS](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/07/animated-buttons-with-css3/)**. Or you could do a custom animation.

Comment: Ooh and that CSS3 trick looks sexy I think I might give that a try.  If not with this project then with something else for sure.  Thank you Boris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could bind a hover event listener on the button

```
$(function(){
    // bind a hover event listener
    $('#hire_me').hover(function(){
        $(this).text('wise choice'); // on hover in, change the text
    },function(){
        $(this).text('hire me'); // on hover out, change the text back
    });
});
```